# Get ubuntu on windows tablet pc

Tags: boot, usb

I want to install ubuntu on my windows tablet pc. I already prepared a boot usb, but I can't select the usb to boot in bios.
(see image)
Perhaps i could boot from usb in the built in UEFI Shell?
Thanks for your help! I can't post an image because I have too less reputation.

Comment: https://www.techradar.com/uk/how-to/computing/how-to-install-ubuntu-onto-a-windows-tablet-1319489 ?

Comment: I had already see this before, but i can't download the 14.04 iso

Comment: Some tablet PCs are 32 bit, Lubuntu has a 32 bit  version of 18.04. Mkusb will make a Persistent drive that will boot BIOS and UEFI. For a UEFI only Live USB you can just extract the ISO to the USB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look if your bios will let you enable "Legacy" boot.

Check if "Secure Boot" is on (needs to be off).

Check if there is a restricion in place for booting from USB. Check if "Legacy USB" is activated.

There might even be a key combo that lets you select where to boot from while startup.

Without really seeing where you are stuck I am just throwing some guesses which may be available to you or not.

Comment: I couldn't find the Legacy boot option and the secure boot already was disabled

Comment: Perhaps someone knows how i can do it in uefi shell